# MultiIndex slicing doesn't work as expected (error involving lexsorted tuples)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a problem, and it just doesn't make sense. I've got a large `pd.DataFrame` that I reduced in size so that I could easily show it in an example (called `test1`):

```
>>> print(test1)

value         TIME                                                      \
star             0            1            2            3            4   
0      1952.205873  1952.205873  1952.205873  1952.205873  1952.205873   
1      1952.226307  1952.226307  1952.226307  1952.226307  1952.226307   
2      1952.246740  1952.246740  1952.246740  1952.246740  1952.246740   
3      1952.267174  1952.267174  1952.267174  1952.267174  1952.267174   

value                        CNTS                                \
star             5              0              1              2   
0      1952.205873  575311.432228  534103.079080  179471.239561   
1      1952.226307  571480.854183  533138.021051  187456.451900   
2      1952.246740  555631.798095  530263.846685  203247.734806   
3      1952.267174  553639.056784  527058.335157  210088.229427   

value                                            
star               3             4            5  
0      121884.201457  39003.397835  2089.321993  
1      122796.312201  39552.401359  2810.010142  
2      123500.068304  39158.050385  2652.409086  
3      124357.387418  38881.565235  2721.908129
```

and I want to perform slice indexing on it. However it just doesn't seem to work. Here is what I try:

```
test.loc[:,(slice(None),0)]
```

and I get this error:

```
*** KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'
```

This isn't the first time I've had this error or asked the question, but I still don't understand how to fix it and what's wrong.

Even more confusing, is that the following code seems to work without a hitch:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 


column_values = ['TIME', 'XPOS']
target = range(0,2)
mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([column_values, target], names=['value', 'target'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=mindex, index=range(10), dtype=float)

print(df.loc[:,(slice(None),0)])
```

I just don't understand what's happening and what's wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only sort `MultiIndex` in columns by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

You can also check [docs - sorting a multiindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex).

Sample (columns are not lexsorted):

```
#your sample, only swap values in column_values
column_values = ['XPOS', 'TIME']
target = range(0,2)
mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([column_values, target], names=['value', 'target'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=mindex, index=range(10), dtype=float)
print (df)
value  XPOS     TIME    
target    0   1    0   1
0       NaN NaN  NaN NaN
1       NaN NaN  NaN NaN
2       NaN NaN  NaN NaN
3       NaN NaN  NaN NaN
4       NaN NaN  NaN NaN
5       NaN NaN  NaN NaN
6       NaN NaN  NaN NaN
7       NaN NaN  NaN NaN
8       NaN NaN  NaN NaN
9       NaN NaN  NaN NaN

print (df.columns.is_lexsorted())
False
```

---

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print (df.columns.is_lexsorted())
True

print(df.loc[:,(slice(None),0)])
value  TIME XPOS
target    0    0
0       NaN  NaN
1       NaN  NaN
2       NaN  NaN
3       NaN  NaN
4       NaN  NaN
5       NaN  NaN
6       NaN  NaN
7       NaN  NaN
8       NaN  NaN
9       NaN  NaN
```